# Cassandra's execute_concurrent not working as it should

Tags: python, python-3.x, concurrency, cassandra

I have written a Python script which reads csv and inserts them into the Cassandra table using both async and concurrent but concurrent is slower than async. My aim to use concurrent was to achieve parallel writes and hence, speed up the task of indexing the csv file in cassandra.

Code using async:

```
for df in chunks:
            futures = []
            df = df.to_dict(orient='records')
            chunk_counter += 1
            for row in df:
                key = str(row["0"])
                row = json.dumps(row, default=str)
                futures.append(
                    self.session.execute_async(
                        insert_sql, [key, "version_1", row]
                    )
                )
                # batch.add(insert_sql, (key, "version_1", row))
            # self.session.execute(batch)
            for future in futures:
                self.log.debug(future)
                continue
```

Code using concurrents:

```
for df in chunks:
            futures = []
            df = df.to_dict(orient='records')
            chunk_counter += 1
            for row in df:
                key = str(row["0"])
                row = json.dumps(row, default=str)
                params = (key, row, )
                futures.append(
                    (
                        insert_sql,
                        params
                    )
                )
            results = execute_concurrent(
                self.session, futures, raise_on_first_error=False)
            for (success, result) in results:
                if not success:
                    self.handle_error(result)  # result will be an Exception
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not setting the `concurrency` parameter of the `execute_concurrent`, and by default it uses 100.

From [documentation](https://datastax.github.io/python-driver/api/cassandra/concurrent.html):

> The **concurrency** parameter controls how many statements will be executed concurrently. When `Cluster.protocol_version` is set to **1** or **2**, it is recommended that this be kept below 100 times the number of core connections per host times the number of connected hosts (see `Cluster.set_core_connections_per_host()`). If that amount is exceeded, the event loop thread may attempt to block on new connection creation, substantially impacting throughput. If protocol_version is **3** or higher, you can safely experiment with higher levels of concurrency.

Comment: Where is this parameter set? I could not find it in the yaml file `/usr/local/etc/cassandra/cassandra.yaml`.

Comment: It’s parameter for function... look into doc

Comment: Yeah got it. Changed the code and now I am unable to understand just one thing, how can I tell to write with 1000(say) concurrency? Where should I change the concurrency number? Could not get this from doc.

Comment: No change in throughput whatsoever, the change in protocol is not reflecting any!

Comment: you shouldn't change the protocol, you simply need to add `concurrency` parameter to function call: `execute_concurrent(self.session, futures, raise_on_first_error=False, concurrency=1000)`

Comment: Increasing concurrency is still not helping, the stats are still stating 2500/sec which was equal to that of async.
`2019-01-17 18:32:50,301 [INFO] root: 1800 's Batch Insert Completed`
`2019-01-17 18:33:24,061 [INFO] root: 1900 's Batch Insert Completed`

Here, 1 batch corresponds to 100000 rows.

Comment: have you tuned the number of in-flight queries as I wrote yesterday?

Comment: yes I did. And the time is 52 mins from 1hr 15 mins without concurrent. As per your experience, what else would scale this up? Running on a multi-node cluster or something?

Comment: Usually async queries help best, batching will help as well, but you’ll need to collect only data for same partition. I have seen when this lead to 5-10x speedup

Comment: My primary keys will be sha256 hash of the Primary key of the column, will having a partition key help here?

Comment: Depends on table schema... if you have partition key == primary key, then it won’t help

Comment: My aim is to have 3 cols: key, row, version where key and version together make the primary key of the table. Should I have partitions here at all?

Comment: In your case, key is the partition key (if you didn’t define composite partition key). But as I remember, every dump is a separate version, so in your case batching won’t work

Comment: And so, `execute_async` is better than concurrent writes, right?
Also, in order to assure that all writes were successful, should I iterate over the array? Line for async is `futures.append( self.session.execute_async( insert_sql, [key, "version_1", row] ) )` and my iteration is `for future in futures: continue`

Comment: I couldn’t say what concurrent uses u der the hood... but regarding futures - yes, it’s better to wait, but maybe you don’t need to submit data in batches... but I’m not sure how this will look like in python.